# Create Multicolored Pie Chart in Android Studio

Tags: android, pie-chart

My app contain a quiz in which I want to show the result of the quiz in a graphical form.

But I don't know about how to create drawable shapes dynamically, and with a pie chart design.

The App has three parameters:

- Correct questions
- Incorrect questions
- Not attempted questions

I  have no idea about how to design a pie chart dynamically and I want to add it to a linear layout.

The graphical representation of result will be like following diagram:

[image: Quiz Result]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very famous library for this the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) .
Using this you can create all types of graphical representation like pie charts,line charts ,bar charts and many more.
The image in your question is a pie chart and to get started with it , you can view this tutorial [here.](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-pie-chart-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library to build the pie chart [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) as you mentioned in the image